# OnePlus One (Bacon) Partition Problem

Tags: twrp, partitions, oneplus-one

I used a custom ROM which completely messed up my partition of OPO. Need partition details of OPO. In TWRP Recovery mode when I select 'Internal Storage' partition, it says'Invalid Partition Selection' & in 'Data' Partition It shows 56 GB available. As a result all my media is stored on data partition & I cannot restore my old backups. Help!!